# Django server returns empty array when using specific server ip but not another

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I start my Django server with an address of `python manage.py runserver 192.168.45.2:8000` and I go to my API endpoint, lets say `http://192.168.45.2:8000/api/products/containers` then all I get back is an empty array `[]` even though the server gives a `200` response.

But when I close and restart the server using address `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and I go to the **exact** same endpoint `http://192.168.45.2:8000/api/products/containers` I get all my API data even though it points to `192.168.45.2`

In django settings file I do have the following:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.45.2', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1','192.168.1.2']
```

I get the same results whether I am using my app through Chrome or using Postman to test my Api's. For both they return empty [] with first IP, and no problem with second IP. 
I must also add that some API's work as expected no matter what address I have, and some do not.

Comment: What's the value of `DEBUG`?

Comment: Can you show corresponding views?

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py set ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

Answer (score 0):

In the end what happened was that because of an example I followed earlier, my url endpoints was in a tuple `{}` and not an array `[]`, this meant that it was picking endpoint "at random" and maybe using an endpoint that would return empty data with what I was giving it.